# Magento 2 Templates: Use `$block` or `$this`?

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

In Magento 2, the `$this` variable no longer refereces to a template's block object.  It refers to a template class

```
 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php
```

However, this template class has a passthrough `__call` method

```
#File: vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func_array([$this->_currentBlock, $method], $args);
}
```

Which ensure any method calls make it through to the actual block.  This also explains why you can't call protected methods from `phtml` templates.

In addition to this though, every (I think?) template has a variable named `$block` populated, which **also** refers to the parent block object.  You can see this in use in Magento's list template

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
//...
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

where the `$block` variable is used, but never explicitly defined.

Other than the differences mentioned above, is there any difference between using one technique over the other?  i.e. Do both `$block` and `$this->currentBlock` refer to the same object?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In a template file, `$block` and `$this->_currentBlock` are the same thing.

Take a look at the [`render`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php#L60) method in the `Php.php` template engine.
Before including the template file, this happens: `$this->_currentBlock = $block;` then the template file is included using a simple `include $fileName;`.
This means that inside a template you are still inside the `Php` template engine. That's why `$this` works, and that's why `$block` is defined.

**[EDIT]**
I just found out that using `$this` inside templates is discouraged.
The php sniffer with the EcgM2 standards shows a warning when using `$this` inside templates.
Replacing `$this` with `$block` makes the warning go away.

Comment: So which is the default object in .phtml file $block or $this.

Comment: What do you mean by default?

Comment: What is the default variable used in a template to access the template's rendering class?
Is there any difference between of these two to access function ?

Comment: It says in ny answer. Both work but it is recommended to use `$block`

Comment: $this & $block are not the same thing

Comment: @GosuPrzmak I did not claim that `$block` and `$this` are the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I've seen they both are almost the same in the PHP TemplateEngineInterface, but remember that in Magento2 you can create custom template engines. Not like Magento1 in which you just had phtml files.

If you see the `TemplateEngineInterface` you cannot see any reference to any method calling the `currentBlock`, so I think the `$this->currentBlock` approach is PHP template specific.

But in order to be independent from the template engine, `$block` should be the correct approach.

I mean that, from theoretical point of view, you could create a different PHP based engine that could not rely on phtml files, but maybe on some other PHP structure.

I assume `$block` as the "right" way for "phtml" mode because it is explicitly passed as context variable.

`$block` and `$this->currentBlock` are the same from a technical point of view, but if they explicitely used `$block` I think we should use it, from a code-styling point of view.

Comment: But neither is $block part of the interface. I'd say it's safe to assume that this implementation is used when you are inside a phtml file. Other implementations won't use the phtml file.

Comment: You are right, I've not been clear in my answer to explain what I mean. I modified my post with more details.