# how to call phtml inside phtml

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, template

I have a custom `phtml` inside I called `attribute.phtml` but it's not working:

```
echo $block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml');
echo $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")
        ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml")
        ->toHtml();
```

Both showing error only.

Answer (score 1):

Pass Block file as, `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description`
Just keep below line in your phtml file,

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the `Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml` you should add important data to the block before layout render it (from the template):

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
```

So according to your needs you can pass block arguments to the `createBlock` method using third argument:

```
/**
 * Block Factory
 *
 * @param  string $type
 * @param  string $name
 * @param  array $arguments
 * @return Element\BlockInterface
 */
public function createBlock($type, $name = '', array $arguments = []);
```

Your code should looks like this (I use the SKU-attribute as an example):

```
$block->getLayout()
        ->createBlock(
            'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template', 
            '', 
            [
                "at_call" => 'getSku',
                "at_code" => 'sku',
                "css_class" => 'sku',
                "at_label" => 'default',
                "add_attribute" => 'itemprop="sku"',
                "product" => $block->getProduct() // Here should be real current product, you should load it in your main block!
            ])
        ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml")
        ->toHtml();
```

**PS:** Try to change `$this` to the `$block` in your code:

```
<?php echo ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml')) ;?>
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

In Magento 2 you should use the `$block` variable inside a template, not `$this`. [Here you can find additional info](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103096/magento-2-templates-use-block-or-this).

Comment: After addin this it break the site

Comment: @Kothari see updated answer. Please, add error from the log to your question.

Comment: @Kothari still have same issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to show phtml inside another phtml

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

If you have any block class already then you can replace `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class with your block class.

**Let me know if you have any doubt !!**