# Product Page review field move google captcha before submit button in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

how can i move google captcha section before submit button in magento 2. i have add website key & secret key in magento google captcha. i have doesn't used any third party extension of google captcha. i have used google captcha only provided by magento. i have no idea how can i move to other position. please help me and thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a two solution to get this down to above the submit button.
I will provide one solution for that.

first you need to create a module or theme to override the files.

- you need to override the catalog_product_view.xml file as well as form.phtml file to make it possible.

override form.phtml file

> theme/Magento_Review/templates/form.phtml

here you need to add below code above the submit button.you need to add only getChildHtml() ?> code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Review\Block\Form $block */
?>
<div class="block review-add">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Your Own Review')) ?></strong></div>
<div class="block-content">
<?php if ($block->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()) : ?>
<form action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAction()) ?>" class="review-form" method="post" id="review-form" data-role="product-review-form" data-bind="scope: 'review-form'">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_fields_before') ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset review-fieldset" data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
        <legend class="legend review-legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("You're reviewing:")) ?></span><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></strong></legend><br />
        <?php if ($block->getRatings() && $block->getRatings()->getSize()) : ?>
        <span id="input-message-box"></span>
        <fieldset class="field required review-field-ratings">
            <legend class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Rating')) ?></span></legend><br/>
            <div class="control">
                <div class="nested" id="product-review-table">
                    <?php foreach ($block->getRatings() as $_rating) : ?>
                        <div class="field choice review-field-rating">
                            <label class="label" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control review-control-vote">
                            <?php $options = $_rating->getOptions();?>
                            <?php $iterator = 1; foreach ($options as $_option) : ?>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="ratings[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getId()) ?>]"
                                    id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>"
                                    value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getId()) ?>"
                                    class="radio"
                                    data-validate="{'rating-required':true}"
                                    aria-labelledby="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_rating_label <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>_label" />
                                <label
                                    class="rating-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($iterator) ?>"
                                    for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>"
                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? __('stars') : __('star'))) ?>"
                                    id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_option->getValue()) ?>_label">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 %2', $iterator, $iterator > 1 ? __('stars') : __('star'))) ?></span>
                                </label>
                                <?php $iterator++; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php endif ?>
        <div class="field review-field-nickname required">
            <label for="nickname_field" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Nickname')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: nickname()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-summary required">
            <label for="summary_field" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Summary')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().title" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field review-field-text required">
            <label for="review_field" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Review')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="detail" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}" data-bind="value: review().detail"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    <div class="actions-toolbar review-form-actions">
        <div class="primary actions-primary">
            <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit Review')) ?></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-role=product-review-form]": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
    },
    "#review-form": {
        "Magento_Review/js/error-placement": {},
        "Magento_Review/js/validate-review": {}
    }
}
</script>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="message info notlogged" id="review-form">
        <div>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%1">Sign in</a> or <a href="%2">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl()), ['a']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
</div>
</div>
```

override catalog_product_view.xml file

```
<referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
<block class="MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha" name="msp-recaptcha_custom" after="-"
       template="MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="msp-recaptcha" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha</item>
                    <item name="zone" xsi:type="string">review</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Also you need to add code to remove default recaptcha block to which is visible on top.

to remove add below code.

```
<referenceBlock name="msp-recaptcha" remove="true" />
```

Also you can use below solution to directly call your block with arguments in phtml.

[how to call phtml inside phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175255/how-to-call-phtml-inside-phtml#answer-175257)

I hope this will work for you.

Thank you.

Comment: hi @nirav thanks for reply, yes its working now. https://imgur.com/RPyirIK

Comment: hi @nirav, i have update magento 2.4.3-p1, this code not work, can you help me ?